# Apache Dynamic Virtual Hosts with multiple domains

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

I've tried this, but it gives me a 403 at /home/*  What I want to achieve is that every folder under home/*/domeenid gets turned into a vhost with the servername being of that folder. Note, that the user folder will also be dynamic. Eg /home/user/domeenid/example.com would turn to example.com

```
NameVirtualHost *:81

<Directory "/home/*/domeenid/">
    Options ExecCGI Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    UseCanonicalName off
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName %-2+
    ServerAlias %-2+
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/*/domeenid/%-2+/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, i think the issue is you have to add ~ or use <DirectoryMatch> instead.

`<Directory ~ "^/www/[0-9]{3}">` [Directory Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)

`<DirectoryMatch "^/www/(.+/)?[0-9]{3}/">` [DirectoryMatch Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directorymatch)

Comment: Nope, the issue is in the   VirtualDocumentRoot